# RowPersisted on two different DAC's are in infinite loop

Tags: acumatica

I currently have custom RowPersisted events on SOLine and POLine in Acumatica. Basically I need to make sure that custom Vendor cost field in SO and unit price field in PO update each other for all the linked PO's and SO's, when user saves them in Acumatica. So I have something like this in POLine_RowPersisted:

```
        soRecExt.UsrVendorCost = line.CuryUnitCost;

        SOOrderEntry graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOOrderEntry>();

        graph.CurrentDocument.Current = soOrd;
        var result = graph.Transactions.Select();

        graph.Transactions.Update(soRec);
        graph.Actions.PressSave();
```

And something like this in SOLine_RowPersisted:

```
        poRec.CuryUnitCost = lineExt.UsrVendorCost;

        POOrderEntry graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<POOrderEntry>();

        graph.CurrentDocument.Current = poOrd;
        var result = graph.Transactions.Select();

        graph.Transactions.Update(poRec);
        graph.Actions.PressSave();
```

So unfortunately when one is updated the whole thing enters infinite loop. I have tried something like this:

```
        POOrderEntry_Extension graphExt = graph.GetExtension<POOrderEntry_Extension>();
        graphExt.RowPersisted.RemoveHandler<SOOrderEntry_Extension>(graphExt.POLine_RowPersisted);
```

However, there is no RowPersisted on graph extension. My events are set to public. Can someone help please?

Comment: I would try this in the graph persist inside a transaction vs rowpersisted. Here is a sample of doing multi graph in a transaction just asked yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48364638/save-in-other-tables-dacs-from-a-graph

Answer (score 0):

The events are registered and triggered by the Base graph so you have to remove them on base graph.

I believe what you're trying to accomplish is more along the lines of:

```
POOrderEntry_Extension graphExt = graph.GetExtension<POOrderEntry_Extension>();
graphExt.Base.RowPersisted.RemoveHandler<POOrderEntry>(graphExt.POLine_RowPersisted);
```

Where 'graph' is of type POOrderEntry then using 'graph' is equivalent to 'graphExt.Base'.

Comment: There is no Base in graphExt

Comment: I basically broke the cycle by comparing if values are not equal from the first line, but would like to know how to accomplish using RemoveHandler. It has to work for extensions.

Comment: Can't you just use graph then? What is 'graph' type? You need to use type POOrderEntry not POOrderEntry_Extension or SOOrderEntry instead of SOOrderEntry_Extension. In your original code, you are using graphExt.RowPersisted where graphExt is a graph extension instead of a base graph. Events are stored in base graph so graphExt won't cut it.

Comment: The part 'graphExt.POLine_RowPersisted' is good because that's the event you want to remove. Perhaps all you need is just to put <POOrderEntry> instead of <POOrderEntry_Extension>.

Comment: basically this is my graph declaration: _public class SOOrderEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>_ so _SOOrderEntry_Extension_ is a graph type. I tried using _graph.RowPersisted.RemoveHandler<POOrderEntry>(graphExt.POLine_RowPersisted)_ and still does not remove the handler.

Comment: This is a basic question but are you sure you aren't mixing up SOOrderEntry and POOrderEntry graph? PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry> is of type PXGraphExtension<T> not of PXGraph type. SOOrderEntry is of PXGraph type. I recall the distinction is important when it comes to event handling. Maybe review my answer here if you haven't already so you can find where's the syntax error in your current code:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46157792/updating-custom-field-is-ending-into-infinite-loop?rq=1